# Can I install Ubuntu Software Center and indicator-sound from 10.10 on 10.04?

Tags: 10.04, indicator, software-center

I wonder if I can manually install Software Center and indicator-sound packages from Maverick to Lucid?

I don´t want to upgrade the whole system, because I´m satisfied with Lucid, but it would be nice to have Maverick Software Center and indicator-sound on Lucid.

I wanted to ask this, because I want to know if I´m going to mess up my system by doing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not do so, unless you can find a supported PPA here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas

You probably will not mess up your system (much) if you try it, though you might not get usable results and be forced to manually downgrade many packages.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I couldn´t wait and I upgraded Software Center and all of the indicators from maverick main PPA. When I have done that, I disabled maverick PPA.

Comment: And have no problems at all. You can see here my new software center; http://img257.imageshack.us/img257/6049/prikazzaslona.png

Comment: If you're satisfied that your problem has been solved by this response, then you should mark it as the accepted answer, by clicking on the tick just below the down arrow on the left. Also voting it up and giving the answerer a little rep is also a cool thing to do.

Comment: Ok. This is my first question here, so I am not quite familiar with all of this. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, ppa:guido-iodice/guiodiclucid has got a lot of maverick features for lucid ;)