# How do I run the latest version of "Ubuntu Software Center" on 10.04?

Tags: 10.04, upgrade, software-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install Ubuntu Software Center and indicator-sound from 10.10 on 10.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5700/can-i-install-ubuntu-software-center-and-indicator-sound-from-10-10-on-10-04)

I am new to ubuntu and juat install Ubuntu 10.04 notebook version,
and my question is can i update the software center to the one in 11.04 and stay in 10.04

thanks,

Comment: Your question seems very similar to [this one.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5700/can-i-install-ubuntu-software-center-and-indicator-sound-from-10-10-on-10-04)

Answer (score 0):

**No AND YES**

,You cant install it without compiling

source-code is available [here](https://launchpad.net/software-center)
you can compile and install it ,BTW support for 1.10 is ended .so upgrade to 12.04 LTS when it releases